# jQuery ajax success callback function definition

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to use jQuery ajax to retrieve data from a server.

I want to put the success callback function definition outside the `.ajax()` block like the following. So do I need to declare the variable `dataFromServer` like the following so that I will be able to use the returned data from the success callback?

I've seen most people define the success callback inside the `.ajax()` block. So is the following code correct if I want to define the success callback outside?

```
var dataFromServer;  //declare the variable first

function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'example.com',
        type: 'GET',
        success : handleData(dataFromServer)
    })
}

function handleData(data) {
    alert(data);
    //do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Just use:

```
function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'example.com',
        type: 'GET',
        success : handleData
    })
}
```

The `success` property requires only a reference to a function, and passes the data as parameter to this function.

You can access your `handleData` function like this because of the way `handleData` is declared. JavaScript will parse your code for function declarations before running it, so you'll be able to use the function in code that's before the actual declaration.  This is known as [hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html).

This doesn't count for functions declared like this, though:

```
var myfunction = function(){}
```

Those are only available when the interpreter passed them.

**[See this question for more information about the 2 ways of declaring functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)**

Comment: @Alnitak, when did the `deferred objects` thing get introduced? I haven't seen it before. Also, it seems slightly messy, since the code that defines what callback to use is in a different location than the actual AJAX call.

Comment: it was introduced in jQuery 1.5 and it's _far_ less messy than using `success:`.  Decoupling the callback from the AJAX is a _good_ thing!  See the notes I just added to the end of my answer.

Comment: @Alnitak, I'll have a look. Let's see if I can be convinced :P

Comment: @Alnitak: Is deferred objects always preferred over success callback? Thanks.

Comment: @tonga IMHO, yes, very much preferred.  If your code had been using `$.get()` for example, it would have been impossible to add an `error:` handler because `$.get` doesn't support it.  However you _can_ add a `.fail` to the deferred _result_ of `$.get`.

Answer (score 205):

The "new" way of doing this since jQuery 1.5 (Jan 2011) is to use deferred objects instead of passing a `success` callback.  You should *return* the result of `$.ajax` and then use the `.done`, `.fail` etc methods to add the callbacks *outside of the `$.ajax` call*.

```
function getData() {
    return $.ajax({
        url : 'example.com',
        type: 'GET'
    });
}

function handleData(data /* , textStatus, jqXHR */ ) {
    alert(data);
    //do some stuff
}

getData().done(handleData);
```

This *decouples* the callback handling from the AJAX handling, allows you to add multiple callbacks, failure callbacks, etc, all without ever needing to modify the original `getData()` function.  Separating the AJAX functionality from the set of actions to be completed afterwards is *a good thing!*.

Deferreds also allow for much easier synchronisation of multiple asynchronous events, which you can't easily do just with `success:`

For example, I could add multiple callbacks, an error handler, and wait for a timer to elapse before continuing:

```
// a trivial timer, just for demo purposes -
// it resolves itself after 5 seconds
var timer = $.Deferred();
setTimeout(timer.resolve, 5000);

// add a done handler _and_ an `error:` handler, even though `getData`
// didn't directly expose that functionality
var ajax = getData().done(handleData).fail(error);

$.when(timer, ajax).done(function() {
    // this won't be called until *both* the AJAX and the 5s timer have finished
});

ajax.done(function(data) {
    // you can add additional callbacks too, even if the AJAX call
    // already finished
});
```

Other parts of jQuery use deferred objects too - you can synchronise jQuery animations with other async operations very easily with them.

Comment: @Cerbrus see the new example, and then consider how you'd do it _without_ deferred objects

Comment: @jbl deferred objects are fantastic.  I _normally_ downvote any answer that promotes use of `success:` because deferreds just work so much better.

Comment: @Cerbrus that's exactly how it's supposed to be interpreted.  Suggest you search here for `user:6782 deferred` for _lots_ more examples.

Comment: How could one utilise this with a form submit event?

Comment: That `alert` though... I'd personally use `console.log(data)` or if it's an array: `console.table(data)` :)

Answer (score 15):

I do not know why you are defining the parameter outside the script. That is unnecessary. Your callback function will be called with the return data as a parameter automatically. It is very possible to define your callback outside the `sucess:` i.e.

```
function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'example.com',
        type: 'GET',
        success : handleData
    })
}

function handleData(data) {
    alert(data);
    //do some stuff
}
```

the handleData function will be called and the parameter passed to it by the ajax function.

Answer (score 6):

Try rewriting your success handler to:

```
success : handleData
```

The success property of the ajax method only requires a reference to a function.

In your handleData function you can take up to 3 parameters:

```
object data
string textStatus
jqXHR jqXHR
```

Answer (score 5):

I would write :

```
var handleData = function (data) {
    alert(data);
    //do some stuff
}


function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'example.com',
        type: 'GET',
        success : handleData
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to declare the variable. Ajax success function automatically takes up to 3 parameters: `Function( Object data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )`

Comment: Somehow had to look for a while to find those default parameters. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

after few hours play with it and nearly become dull. miracle came to me, it work.

```
<pre>


var listname = [];   


 $.ajax({
    url : wedding, // change to your local url, this not work with absolute url
    success: function (data) {
       callback(data);
    }
});

function callback(data) {
      $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
            if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
             //   $('#displayImage1').append( "<img src='" + wedding + val +"'>" );
                 listname.push(val);
            } 
        });
}

function myfunction() {

alert (listname);

}

</pre>
```

Comment: you do not need to put another function call for success. you can directly say `success : callback` jquery will trigger your function called `callback` with the `data` parameter in it.

Answer (score -1):

In your component i.e angular JS code:

```
function getData(){
    window.location.href = 'http://localhost:1036/api/Employee/GetExcelData';
}
```