# How do you write to a global function with JQuery and Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to return data from a AJAX handler into a global variable. I have tried making the call non asyc. The difficulty I am having is when I create a global variable and I make reference to that global variable the value becomes undefined outside the Ajax request. I have even tried calling a function using my success callback without any luck. Here is what it looks like at the moment. I made the call sync with a previous question being addressed [jQuery ajax success callback function definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754619/jquery-ajax-success-callback-function-definition)

```
config();
function config()
{
    var dataBool;
    var db_test;
    $.ajax({asyc: false,
            url: 'config.php',
            dataType: "text",
            data:{db_test:1},
            type: "POST",
            success: dataStuff
    });
    function dataStuff(data)
    {
        dataBool = data;
    }

}
```

Comment: It is undefined outside the  $.ajax and and inside the config (which i guess is what you are looking for) because of the typo `asyc`, it is still going as sync due to the typo.

Answer (score 2):

If you want dataBool to be a global variable... it needs to be a global variable, not a local variable

```
var dataBool;
config();
function config()
{
    var db_test;
    $.ajax({url: 'config.php',
            dataType: "text",
            data:{db_test:1},
            type: "POST",
            success: dataStuff
    });
    function dataStuff(data)
    {
        dataBool = data;
    }

}
```

`asyc: false` is unnecessary and misspelled. The param is `async:false`, so that option had no effect, and you don't need it anyways.

Comment: He does need it (your solution will cause problems with an async call), but he shouldn't (he should really be using the callback flow an not a global var).