# Why don't 'alert' show new value of a variable set from a input's value?

Tags: jquery

After a submit button is clicked, outside 'click' event I use 'alert' to display the variable which is assigned a value from an input text. Why was a blank value returned? Then, I tried to create a function containing an 'alert' for that variable, and I used this function in 'click' event that resulted in value of textbox is shown. Why does this happen? How are two operation different?
HTML:

```
<form id="myForm">Your name:
    <input type="text" id="nametxt" />
    <input type="button" value="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

jQuery: (First experiment)

```
var name = "";
$("#submit").click(function(){    
    name = $("#nametxt").val();
});
    alert(name); ==============> Unexpected result: blank value
```

jQuery: (Second experiment)

```
var name = "";

var makeSentence =  function() {
    return name + " is nice!";
}

var myFunc = function() {

    alert(makeSentence());
}

$( "#submit" ).click(function() {
   name = $('#nametxt').val();
   myFunc(); ==========================> Expected result: "yourname is nice!" is alerted.
});
```

Why do experiment 2 display name's value but experiment 1 don't?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasperlee/2AVQf/

Comment: because within the submit is another scope, is more like private scope, thats why you will never get the value outside the scope, you can refer to this link for some idea, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754619/jquery-ajax-success-callback-function-definition, a callback is needed if you want the value to be out of the scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var name = "";
$("#submit").click(function(){    
    name = $("#nametxt").val();
});
alert(name);
```

In this example `name` is set to `blank.` string.
Blank value will be alerted as the `alert` function is getting executed when the page loads.

This is the expected behavior not unexpected.

Please note that `alert` gets executed only once, in this example, when the page loaded.

However, the `anonymous function` associated with the `submit` event updates the `name` variable.

You can verify it by accessing the `name` variable in `Javascript Console`

---

```
var name = "";

var makeSentence =  function() {
    return name + " is nice!";
}

var myFunc = function() { 
    alert(makeSentence());
}

$( "#submit" ).click(function() {
   name = $('#nametxt').val();
   myFunc();
});
```

In this example the `alert` function is getting executed when `myFun` is invoked. `myFunc` in turn is invoked when the `#submit` is clicked.

The `name` variable is getting set when the `anonymous function` associated with the `click` event of the `#submit` is executed.

`alert` is getting as many times the `#submit` is clicked in this example.

Answer (score 2):

In your first experiment, your `alert()` is outside the function definition, which means it is called immediately after your function is defined, not when you click on your button.  Here's a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/posgarou/SQNU5/) based on your experiment 1.

As an aside, you might consider using `console.log()` for testing rather than `alert()`. Personally I think it's a lot more convenient.