# How can I add additional parameters to my Ajax callback?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I think I might have done this... not in the best way. But it's working and the result is returned in my *data* object. Now I need to pass on some additional parameters. How can I call `handleData()` with additional parameters? I've tried this:

```
handleData({'likes' : true})
```

But that deletes the `data` object which is returned from the Ajax call.

Here is my code:

```
// My global Ajax function to 'set' data
$.fn.setData = function(url, params){
    return $.ajax({
        url: site_url + url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: params
    });
}    

function registerLike() {
    var like    = $('.interaction .like')
    var status  = $(like).data('status');
    var count   = $(like).data('count');

    like.click(function(){
        if(!liked){
            // I need to pass adition parameters here
            like.setData('action/like', {'id' : id}).done(handleData());
        } else {
            // and here
            like.setData('action/unlike', {'id' : id}).done(handleData());
        }
    });

    function handleData(data){
        if(data.success) {

            if(data.likes){
                count = count+1;
                liked = 1;
            } else {
                if(count > 0) {
                    count = count-1;
                } else {
                    count = 0;
                }
                liked = 0;
            }

            $('.interaction .like .icon').toggleClass('el-icon-heart');
            $('.like-count').html(count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps look into using the `success` handler of the `ajax` method, defining locally scoped variables each time and then calling `handleData` through that as opposed to using `done`

Comment: @RobSchmuecker No, not according to Alnitak "This decouples the callback handling from the AJAX handling, allows you to add multiple callbacks" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754619/jquery-ajax-success-callback-function-definition By returning the data,

Comment: Fair enough, has always done the trick for me though.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker While a valid workaround, it's still a workaround

Comment: @JuanMendes I don't really understand?  http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/j5L49/ Here you can access the locally scoped variables in the `success` callback just fine?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker I may be wrong, but I think the point is that the success handler may need to be used somewhere else, so it can't be defined in the same closure

Comment: @JuanMendes ah ok right, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always create a wrapper with an anonymous function:

```
like.setData('action/unlike', {'id' : id}).done(function(response){
    myCallback(response, extraData);
});
```

Comment: This is the easiest way. I just love `Function.bind` though

Answer (score 1):

[Amir's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25147603/227299) is a good one. However, it is generalized in [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
like.setData('action/unlike', {'id' : id}).done( 
    myCallback.bind(this, extraData) 
);
```

Note that your function will be called like `myCallback(extraData, response)`, not `myCallback(response, extraData)`. If you really need `extraData` to be passed after the call time arguments, you can implement your own bind that appends the bound arguments instead of prepending them.

Ext-JS has a bind function that lets you choose where to insert the bound arguments.

```
/**
 * Create a new function from the provided `fn`, change `this` to the provided scope, optionally
 * overrides arguments for the call. (Defaults to the arguments passed by the caller)
 *
 * {@link Ext#bind Ext.bind} is alias for {@link Ext.Function#bind Ext.Function.bind}
 *
 * @param {Function} fn The function to delegate.
 * @param {Object} scope (optional) The scope (`this` reference) in which the function is executed.
 * **If omitted, defaults to the default global environment object (usually the browser window).**
 * @param {Array} args (optional) Overrides arguments for the call. (Defaults to the arguments passed by the caller)
 * @param {Boolean/Number} appendArgs (optional) if True args are appended to call args instead of overriding,
 * if a number the args are inserted at the specified position
 * @return {Function} The new function
 */
bind: function(fn, scope, args, appendArgs) {
    if (arguments.length === 2) {
        return function() {
            return fn.apply(scope, arguments);
        };
    }

    var method = fn,
        slice = Array.prototype.slice;

    return function() {
        var callArgs = args || arguments;

        if (appendArgs === true) {
            callArgs = slice.call(arguments, 0);
            callArgs = callArgs.concat(args);
        }
        else if (typeof appendArgs == 'number') {
            callArgs = slice.call(arguments, 0); // copy arguments first
            Ext.Array.insert(callArgs, appendArgs, args);
        }

        return method.apply(scope || Ext.global, callArgs);
    };
},
```

See http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Function-method-bind