# Get AJAX-result via function into variable

Tags: jquery

I try to get an ajax-result via function into a variable. But `var output` is always undefined. What am I doing wrong? I guess the problem is, that the ajax request takes some time, while the output is done immediately

```
var data = { 'something': 'anything' };
var output = ajaxed(data);
console.log(output);

function ajaxed(data) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/script.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json"
    })
    .done(function( json ) {
        return json.response;
    });
}
```

Comment: Very good question and I looked up this answer which uses deferred objects which might work in this case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14754681/2048391

Comment: your guess is correct.  The "fix" is to ensure that all of your processing on the `json.response` variable is done from code that's invoked from within that `.done` callback.   In fact your code should read `return $.ajax(...).then(function(json) { return json.response })` at which point the result of `ajaxed(data)` will not be the data itself, but a _promise_ to return the correct data some time later.  You can then attach additional `.then` handlers to that promise.

Answer (score -1):

If you are sending data vía POST, just try to define each variable with an individual name like this:

```
var output = ajaxed(myData);

$.post( '/script.php', { dataToBeProcessed: myData }, function(data) { 
    return data[0].response;
}, "json");
```

Comment: I don't see what I'm doing wrong, as I think each variable has an individual name in my attempt.

Comment: Have you tried this: json[0].response ??

Comment: yes, but it doesn't work :-(  `TypeError: json[0] is undefined`

Comment: This does not even remotely answer the question.  The way the parameters are supplied is _utterly irrelevant_ to the issue of how the OP handles the asynchronous results.

Comment: And are you using some kind of "echo json_encode(...." in your script.php code?