# How to make code wait X seconds after clicking a button before continuing?

Tags: javascript, wait

I’m trying to make a script that clicks on a page button, waits *X* seconds (for the result of the click to take place), and then continues.

How can I implement the waiting part?

Comment: as per my guess, @Daniel is talking something like a call back function rather than just setTimeout

Comment: is the button making a call to something and fetching data?  if so, you may want to search for AJAX calls and promises/callbacks

Comment: @Daniel, if my guess is right, use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754619/jquery-ajax-success-callback-function-definition

Comment: @SunilBN, that seems really promising!!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

using setTimeout, which executes only once after the delay provided

```
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log('gets printed only once after 3 seconds')
  //logic
},3000);
```

using setInterval , which executes repeatedly after the delay provided

```
setInterval(function(){
  console.log('get printed on every 3 second ')
},3000);
```

`clearTimeout` and `clearInterval` is used to clear them up !!!

Comment: This worked very well! I would suggest inserting "//logic" after console.log on your second example for clarity.   
Also, would help to show an example with the syntax for using "clearTimeout." Thanks for the great answer.

Comment: It is working in console fine but I want to use it with a script for chrome extension, it doesn't work through extension script.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) which executes a code snippet after a specified delay.:

```js
var timeoutID;

function delayedAlert() {
  timeoutID = setTimeout(slowAlert, 2000);
}

function slowAlert() {
  alert("That was really slow!");
}

function clearAlert() {
  clearTimeout(timeoutID);
}
```

```html
<p>Live Example</p>
<button onclick="delayedAlert();">Show an alert box after two seconds</button>
<p></p>
<button onclick="clearAlert();">Cancel alert before it happens</button>
```

Or you can use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) which calls a function or executes a code snippet repeatedly, with a fixed time delay between each call to that function:

```js
function KeepSayingHello(){
  setInterval(function () {alert("Hello")}, 3000);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="KeepSayingHello()">Click me to keep saying hello every 3 seconds</button>
```

Comment: do you mean `setInterval()` in the second part?

Comment: Yes @Daniel, sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score -1):

Somehow setTimeout doesn't do anything for me. But window.setTimeout does.

```html
window.setTimeout(function() {
  alert("Hello! This runs after 5 seconds delay!");
}, 5000);
```