# How do I execute jquery function after the db is updated by php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Okay, so what I'm trying to do is delete a row from my DB. Then update my list in html/php.

```
function deleteThis(blogid) {
var result="";
 $.ajax({
  url: 'deleter.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: { id: blogid },
  success:function(data) {

     result = data; 
     alert(result);
          }
});
if (result!=""){

  $("#contentContainer").html(showAll("contentAllBlogs"));
};
};
```

Using this code (above), I am able to successfully delete data from my database. My problem is reloading the #contentContainer after the DB has been updated.

If I use setTimeout, and wait a few seconds before triggering this code (below)

```
$("#contentContainer").html(showAll("contentAllBlogs"));
```

It actually works, my list gets updated. But I don't want to use setTimeout. Is there a way to trigger this code after the DB is finished updating?

Please, help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Put the function into the success where it belongs

Comment: Why you don't put `$("#contentContainer").html(showAll("contentAllBlogs"));` inside the success method?

Comment: I actually did try that. But it doesn't work. I think this is what happens. 

The  code 

$("#contentContainer").html(showAll("contentAllBlogs"));

gets triggered before the DB is finished updating.

Comment: Have a look at the second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754619/jquery-ajax-success-callback-function-definition - if your php returns before updating the DB, then you need to change the php

Comment: Sir, are you implying to use  .done() ?  i tried it, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You can use `complete` setting of `ajax` request for this, [see here](http://pastebin.com/tPKcfvUa).

Comment: Thank you very much Sir !! That was neat. Now I don't need all the setInterval I wrote. They're ugly. lols haha Thanks again.

Comment: You're very welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can not access result data out the ajax function because
in if() statement result value is undefined.

```
function deleteThis(blogid) {
var result="";
 $.ajax({
  url: 'deleter.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: { id: blogid },
  success:function(data) {

     result = data; 
     displayData();
          }
});

function displayData(){
$("#contentContainer").html(showAll("contentAllBlogs"));
}
```

Comment: Are there other ways to fix this without using setInterval?

Comment: But the alert inside the result also shows no value