# Ajax fails/error after calling asmx to generate itexsharp pdf

Tags: javascript, c#, asmx

I have external javascript invoice.js which calls asmx service as follows to generate and saves invoice.pdf

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/CommonService.asmx/GenerateInvoice",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
               alert('Success');
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert('error');
            }
        }).done(function () {//this will execute after completing ajax call also u can pass the same response to this method

            var dXmlhttp;


            var colUrl = /Service.svc/json/somefunction";
            var columnData = {
                "objList": {
                    "Mappingid": mappingid,
                    "JsonArray": JsonInvoiceArray


                }
            };
            var parmColum = JSON.stringify(columnData);

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                colHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                colHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            colHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (colHttp.readyState == 4 && colHttp.status == 200) {
                    var result = JSON.parse(colHttp.responseText);

                    }
                }
            }
            colHttp.open("POST", colUrl, true);
            colHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            colHttp.send(parmColum);
        });
```

In Itextsharp pdf generating code will always run `alert('error');`  and it wont call done().
GenerateInvoice calls asmx to create pdf and it will save pdf.

Comment: because your webmethod is returning an error that is why its going to error part. And also have look at the post below you will get know how done works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754619/jquery-ajax-success-callback-function-definition/14754681#14754681

Comment: After creating pdf, it returns error.  I replaced HttpContext.Current.Response.End(); with                                                      HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush(); 
 HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true; 
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();                             still getting error

Comment: will you post your webmethod code?