# AJAX Response to function (prevent async false)

Tags: javascript, ajax

i have an issue with an AJAX call to give the response to the main function. Right now i use async false which i know is odd and i try to solve it but fail all the time.

This works (async false):

```
function printTable(){
    var $table = $('#Table');

    var view_data;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/api/getdata',
        success: function(response) {

        var TableData = [];

        for(var i =0;i < response.length ;i++){
                    var item = response[i];

        var sessionID = item.sessionID;

                    if(sessionID){

                        $.ajax({
                        async: false,
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '/api/getNickname',
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                        id: sessionID,
                        },
                        success: function(response){
                            view_data = response;
                        }
                     });

}

TableData.push({
                        _id: item._id,
                        datum: item.datum,
                        uhrzeit: item.uhrzeit,
                        session: view_data,
                        });

        }

        $table.bootstrapTable({data: TableData});
        $table.bootstrapTable('togglePagination');
            }   
    })
}
```

I tried the suggestion from here: [Assigning ajax response to global variable without using async: false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39447107/assigning-ajax-response-to-global-variable-without-using-async-false) but it fails as view_data is undefined.

```
function printTable(){
    var $table = $('#Table');

    var view_data;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/api/getdata',
        success: function(response) {

        var TableData = [];

        for(var i =0;i < response.length ;i++){
                    var item = response[i];

        var sessionID = item.sessionID;

                    if(sessionID){

                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/api/getNickname',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                    id: sessionID,
                    }
                 }).done(function(response){
                    test(response)
                 });

                 function test(response){
                     view_data = response;
                     return view_data;
                 }

            }

}

TableData.push({
                        _id: item._id,
                        datum: item.datum,
                        uhrzeit: item.uhrzeit,
                        session: view_data,
                        });

        }

        $table.bootstrapTable({data: TableData});
        $table.bootstrapTable('togglePagination');
            }   
    })
}
```

What i realized is if i put alert(view_data); before the push it works!? Im not that deep into JS/AJAX as is still learn it, so i hope someone might give me a hint or can help..
How can i pass var view_data to the main function without using async false?

Thanks...

Comment: The code from the "main function" which uses the result of the ajax call should be placed in a callback.  You should stop trying to "Return" values from functions that are async because it *doesn't work*.

Answer (score 0):

**This has to do with asynchronous code**

When you specify `async: false`, you are telling the code to **wait** until this HTTP call is completed.

But without `async: false` your http call is made **asynchronously** i.e. program will continue its execution without actually waiting for HTTP call to complete and your `success` function will only executed when HTTP call response is returned
which will take 2 3 sec but you are accessing your view_data which is undefined at that time.

What you can do is move your `push` code inside the `success` function:

function printTable(){
    var $table = $('#Table');

```
var view_data;

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/api/getdata',
    success: function(response) {

    var TableData = [];

    for(var i =0;i < response.length ;i++){
                var item = response[i];

    var sessionID = item.sessionID;

                if(sessionID){

                    $.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/api/getNickname',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                    id: sessionID,
                    },
                    success: function(response){
                        view_data = response;
                        TableData.push({  // <- like this
                    _id: item._id,
                    datum: item.datum,
                    uhrzeit: item.uhrzeit,
                    session: view_data,
                    });
                   $table.bootstrapTable({data: TableData});
                   $table.bootstrapTable('togglePagination');


                    }
                 });

}

    }

        }   
})
```

}

Comment: I want to prevent async false.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the thing when JS is asynchronously, so when you use async: false, it means code the below code wont execute until you get respond.
Declare variable(view_data) -> send asynchronously AJAX request(you dont wait for respond) -> below code excuted

Declare variable(view_data) -> send synchronously AJAX request(you wait for respond) -> assign respond to view_data -> below code excuted

so you write your j query into success after ajax request execute and you get respond

```
function printCatchTable() {
    var $table = $("#TableLastCaught");

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/lastcaught",
        success: function(response) {
            var faengeTableData = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                var item = response[i];

                var sessionID = item.sessionID;

                if (sessionID) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/api/getSessionNickname",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            id: sessionID
                        },
                        success: function(response) {
                            //Keep Pushing on Array
                            faengeTableData.push({
                                _id: item._id,
                                datum: item.datum,
                                uhrzeit: item.uhrzeit,
                                fischart: item.fischart,
                                gewicht: item.gewicht,
                                laenge: item.laenge,
                                koeder: item.koeder,
                                montage: item.montage,
                                gewaesser: item.gewaesser,
                                temperatur: item.temperatur,
                                luftdruck: item.luftdruck,
                                bilder: fileNames,
                                edit: item._id,
                                session: response
                            });

                            //run jquery on last element
                            if(i === response.length){//if i === response.length, it means its final element so you run jquery table
                                $table.bootstrapTable({ data: faengeTableData });
                                $table.bootstrapTable("togglePagination");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }


            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I wanted to prevent async false but this only works with async false...

Comment: sorry i forgot to remove async false from code, but this should work cause you just run jquery with all elements get pushed on array (faengeTableData )