# RequestMapping head to know if email exist or not

Tags: spring

I use spring boot

I would like to check if an email address alread exist in the system.
I created this

```
@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.HEAD }, value={"/email"})
public ResponseEntity<Boolean> checkEmailexist(@RequestParam String value){
    return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.checkIfEmailExist(value));
}
```

If i check the result of userService.checkIfEmailExist, depending of the value, I get true or false...

Result from the call it's alway undefined

```
 $.ajax({
     url: '/email?value=' + usernameValue.value,
     type: 'HEAD',
     success: function (result) {
     console.log(result);
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not an answer but rather a set of steps to check that will (hopefully) help you to find a solution:

1. Make sure your annotations are correct - whether the `@RestController` annotation is used properly, what is the result, etc.
2. As a generalization of "1" try to understand whether the issue is on server at all
   For that run CURL query/use postman - whatever on a deployed server and see the result.
3. If the issue is on the client side try to understand the status code of the request. I'm not a jquery pro (I understand this is a jquery syntax), but read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754619/jquery-ajax-success-callback-function-definition) and especially the answer with 'done' method - probably its a better way to work anyway, or at least put a jquery tag on the question so that the relevant people could read it and respond.